# Karate API -> JSON Request -> Base field in JSON not being sent in request (works in Postman)

Tags: karate

My JSON request has a base value that is the top object.

Sample:
{

```
  "partner_id": "6f4a3092-1b11-48c0-8a11-ae455b327ed8",
  "borrowers": [
    {
      "loan": {
        "loan_number": "89898989898222",
```

The partner_id is not being sent with the rest of the request.

Does this first object require special treatment to be sent with the rest of the request?

It feels like it should 'just work'

Comment: if this is true it is a serious problem. works for me though. follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0):

In my steps to file a bug, it started working in picking up the base object.